# aboutToQuit signal not called in Android environment?

Tags: android, qt, qml

How can i catch QApplication::aboutToQuit on Android environment ? 
It works perfectly on Windows but it's never called when user close the application on Android.

I'm using Qt 5.12.2, QQuick2.

It does not work on Android Emulator and neither on my Android phone.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);    
    QuitEventHandle test;
    QObject::connect(&app, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, &test, &QuitEventHandle::aboutToQuit);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;        

    return app.exec();
}

class QuitEventHandle : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QuitEventHandle(QObject *parent=nullptr);
    virtual ~QuitEventHandle() override;

public slots:
    void aboutToQuit();
};

QuitEventHandle::QuitEventHandle(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}
QuitEventHandle::~QuitEventHandle()
{
}

void QuitEventHandle::aboutToQuit()
{
    int a = 2;
}
```

Comment: Check out this, I think it's what you want: https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qguiapplication.html#applicationState (and if you solve your problem, feel free to write an answer explaining your solution).

Comment: Thank you, that’s effectively what I need, the applicationStateChanged (with the application’s state: Qt::ApplicationSuspended) is called just before user can close the application. <br/>
In fact, I need to save some application's states and clean up the resource when the application is closed. So, my solution is: <br/>
    Use applicationStateChanged to save my application’s states 
    Let’s the Android clean up for me for the resource problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution :

- Use `QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged` to save application's states.
- In the case of Windows, clean up the resource with: `QApplication::aboutToQuit`
- In the case of Android, let the system clean up the resource.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought. The lifecycle of application on Android is quite different than what you can see on PC. When the user "close" an app, it is not necessarily closed. Instead it goes through several stages: `onPause`, `onStop` and `onDestroyed`.

So it could be that the signal is not emitted because even if the application is closed, the `QApplication` is still running.

If you want to get more info about Android's Activity lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

You may be able to track the state of the application using [`QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state)`](http://%20https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#applicationStateChanged)

Comment: Thank you for the link of Android's Activity lifecycle. The QuiApplication::applicationStateChanged is effectively what i need to save some states.